# What type is this fan motor and how best can I control its speed?

Tags: motor, fan

This is from an old Westinghouse fan and I am not clear on this motor type and how to best control its speed.

[image: Westinghouse Fan Motor]

Answer (score 2):

This is a Shaded Pole Induction motor. Simple, Robust, Ineffecient. Voltage control will work on a fan type of load. This is not ideal but it is simple and robust.

Comment: So I can apply simple rheostat (resistance) to the line voltage then?

Comment: @Chris1964 No, rheostat control (though it would actually work) is not what you would use. You could use a standard fan Triac control ( an example here: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B004Q01PQI/ref=psdc_13397451_t2_B000X4PMRY) or an autotransformer (fixed switch positions) unit such as these: http://www.fansandspares.co.uk/assets/shop/datasheets/1213782136_Pages_from_big_book_of_fans_&_spares-115.pdf

Comment: Thanks!  I found a KB Electronics Solid State Motor Speed Control Part# KBWC-15K which supposedly supports a shaded pole motor and has a triac design.                I looked up triac speed control apparently a triac turns on and off really fast (variable to some secondary voltage that is controlled by a rheostat) and turns the load on and off at an adjustable rate. So essentially the fan gets full power but in time slices. Do I have this right?